# PDFs not opening in WaterFox, even after installing FoxIt

Tags: firefox, pdf

When I click on a pdf it automatically downloads and the download manager pops up but no program opens. I downloaded FoxIt for pdfs but still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you have the latest version of WaterFox by going to the Waterfox button -> Help -> About.

Now, follow this:

1. Open a new tab and go to `about:preferences` and press Enter.
2. Click on the Applications button.
3. Type in `PDF` into the search box.
4. ***For the Action, change it to `Use Other...` and a pop-up box will appear.
5. Select Foxit Reader from the list and press OK. If you cannot see/find Foxit Reader from the list, click on Browse... and then find the program manually (should be somewhere in Program Files).
6. Press OK and you should be done.

For step 4***, you can select the Foxit Reader plugin if you want to view the file inside your browser.

NOTE: Mozilla are currently working on a PDF.js reader that automatically converts the PDF file to open web language. This is a work in progress, but it is more secure and faster than using another separate program, but you might have some issues with some PDF files. If you are interested, see [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs/) for the PDF.js extension.

Answer (score 0):

## Waterfox 56 "Classic", 2020

I encountered the same issue.

1. Click on `Tools` then `Options` (press `Alt` is the file menu is missing or go to `about:preferences` in the address bar).
2. Click on the `Applications` menu.
3. Search for `pdf`.
4. Select `Preview in Waterfox`.

No restart is required.

## Webmasters

The following works in Gecko (Waterfox), Trident (IE18 or "Edge") and Blink (Chrome):

```
<object data="example.pdf"></object>
```